# Magento 2: Checking Customer Logged In not work in navigation menu

Tags: magento2, cache, navigation, home

I want to add some link to navigation menu in magento 2. Some link will display after checking customer logged in or not. I tried to create a plugin.

```
namespace AIS\Custom\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;

class Topmenu
{
    protected $nodeFactory;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
    }

    public function beforeGetHtml(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
        $outermostClass = '',
        $childrenWrapClass = '',
        $limit = 0
    ) {
        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => $this->getProviderNode(),
                'idField' => 'id',
                'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);

        if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
                [
                    'data' => $this->getMyCourseNode(),
                    'idField' => 'id',
                    'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
                ]
            );
            $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
        }
    }

    protected function getProviderNode()
    {
        return [
            'name' => __('Provider'),
            'id' => 'nav-provider',
            'url' => 'http://www.example.com/',
            'has_active' => false,
            'is_active' => false // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
        ];
    }

    protected function getMyCourseNode()
    {
        return [
            'name' => __('My Course'),
            'id' => 'nav-mycourse',
            'url' => 'http://www.example.com/',
            'has_active' => false,
            'is_active' => false // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
        ];
    }

    protected function getCacheLifetime()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

All page seems fine but the home page is not following the checking. It will display "My Course" button after customer logout. I try to disable the cache and it cannot fix the problem.

Comment: Finally I aborted to use Plugin to do this. I try to override Topmenu Block and set the cache life time to 1 and it is success. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternative sample code as below.

```
$ObjectManager= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$context = $ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
return $isLoggedIn;
```

Above is reference code only. You can inject `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` in your constructor instead of `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`

Comment: Sorry, it still not do the checking in homepage. I think it is about the cache but I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code after

```
$subject->setCacheable(false);
```

In  `if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {`

### BY flush cache after logout

**Another good idea to flush  block  cache after logout.**

Fire an event on `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_logout`

```
<?php
namespace [Vendorname]\[ModuleName]\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
/**
 * @category   Devamitbera
 * @author     Amit Bera <dev.amitbera@gmail.com>
 * @website    http://www.amitbera.com
* @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
class [MyObserverClass]  implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_cacheTypeList;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
    ) {

        $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* Block cache flush */
        $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType('block_html');

        $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType('customer_notification');
        /* Full page cache  flush */
        $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType('full_page');

        return $this;
    }


}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it still not working

Answer (score 1):

`Magento\Customer\Model\Session` doesn't work properly if cache is enabled. So You have to set **cacheable="false"** or keep cache disabled in order to use `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` in your constructor.

You can use below method instead. This will work even if your cahce is enabled.

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
) 
{
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}
...
...

$customer = $this->_customerSession->create();
if($customer->isLoggedIn){
    echo "customer is logged in";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me:

Use `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` class to get value for `\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH`. After that overwrite `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu::getCacheKeyInfo()` to add information about logged customer to block's cache key info (or create plugin):

```
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
   $keyInfo = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
   $keyInfo[] = $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
   return $keyInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Factory** class.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory
 */
protected $customerSessionFactory;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory
    ....
) 
{
    ....
    $this->customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
    ....
}

public function yourFunctionName(){
  ...
  $customerSession = $this->customerSessionFactory->create();
  $customerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
  $isLoggedIn = $customerSession->isLoggedIn();
  ...
}
```